# frostDays doesn't exist

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to end up with 100 frostDays but I think I put it wrong.

Its only a for loop + Array code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

  System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
  int nyrHiti = RandNum.Next(-10, 50);
  Console.WriteLine(nyrHiti);
  int[] frostDays = new int[100];

}

Console.ReadLine();                    

Console.WriteLine(frostDays[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Nothing (directly) related with the question, ut why can't I edit this question to reformat the code layout ?  I don't see the link as I usually do...

Answer (score 6):

I have no idea what you're doing, but your code has several common errors that we can easily fix:

```
System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
int[] frostDays = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int nyrHiti = RandNum.Next(-10, 50);
    Console.WriteLine(nyrHiti);
    frostDays[i] = nyrHiti;
}
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(frostDays[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This probably gets you close to what you intended. You need to declare your instance of `Random` outside of the loop, and `frostDays` outside the `for` so it's still in scope when you need afterwards, and you need to assign to `frostDays[i]` in the loop otherwise it's just the zero array of length 100.

Comment: Good guess on setting `frostDays` equal to `nyriHiti`. I never would have guessed that.

Comment: Probably gets closest to what was intended.

Comment: ye and basicly I want to write, "Day 3 was" + nyrhiti + "degrees" thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because `frostDays` has local scope to your `for-loop`. It must be declared outside of the loop to be able to be used by `Console.WriteLine(...)`. But, it is going to be full of 0's so I am not sure what you intended to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is declared inside the loop, its visibility is restricted to this loop.  Declare it outside the loop and it will work.

```
int[] frostDays = new int[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{    
    System.Random RandNum = new System.Random();
    int nyrHiti = RandNum.Next(-10, 50);
    Console.WriteLine(nyrHiti);
}
Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(frostDays[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, as  you don't do anything with it, it will return 0 each time.    Maybe what you want is to set the `i`th value of the tab to the random number you just picked ?  In this case, use `frostDays[i] = nyrHiti` at the end of the loop's body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define frostDays outside the loop.